# Why isn't my DataAdapter->Update working on a new form?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a main Form. There is a linklabel. If i click on it, a new form will open, and there is a datagrid and a button on it. The datagrid will be filled with data on the new forms Load event.
I bind the datasource this way:

```
void BindDataSource( BindingSource^ BS, SqlDataAdapter^ DA, DataGridView^ DG, String^ SQLCommand )
{
DG->DataSource = BS;

//InsertDataToDataGrid( "select * from myTable", dataGridView10 );  
String^ connectionString = "database=myDataBase;server=myServer;UID=UserID;PWD=Password;";

// Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
DA = gcnew SqlDataAdapter( SQLCommand, connectionString);

gcnew SqlCommandBuilder( DA );

DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable();
DA->Fill( table );
BS->DataSource = table;

}//BindDataSource
```

If i click the button it should save the changes.

I save it like this:
   `dAPcExceptions->Update( ( DataTable^ )bSPCExceptions->DataSource );`

I use this method on the main Form and it is working fine.
However if i click the button i get an error:
`update requires a valid updatecommand when passed datarow collection with modified rows`

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you area creating a SqlDataAdapter and returing it for future uses. So you must use a track reference to make SqlDataAdapter parameter as input/output.

```
void BindDataSource( BindingSource^ BS, SqlDataAdapter^% DA, DataGridView^ DG, String^ SQLCommand ) 
{
...
// Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
DA = gcnew SqlDataAdapter( SQLCommand, connectionString);
...
}//BindDataSource
```